# Obtener error que devuelve el servidor con Volley

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual consumo un servicio externo y para esto, estoy usando la librería [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) de Google. Estoy intentando procesar el error con la estructura:

```
{
"message": "invalid public_key",
"error": "not_found",
"status": 404,
"cause": [
    {
        "code": "1001",
        "description": "public_key not found"
    }
]
}
```

pero [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) directamente llama al metodo onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
devolviendo un error genérico, en este caso 404.
¿Como debo proceder para obtener dicha estructura y obtener los datos que necesito?

Código de esquema de servicios:

```
mProgress = UIComponents.showProgressDialog(this);
    Request<?> requestCreditCard = RequestFactory.getCreditCard(this,
            getString(R.string.base_url),
            getString(R.string.payment_methods_url),
            getString(R.string.public_key),
            new OkInterface() {
                @Override
                public void onOkResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
                    loadCreditCards(response);
                }
            },
            new ErrorInterface() {
                @Override
                public void onShowErrorResponse() {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.without_results, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void doErrorHandler() {
                    UIComponents.hideProgressDialog(mProgress);
                }


            });
    RequestNetworkCache.getmQueue().add(requestCreditCard);


public class BaseRequestApi extends JsonArrayRequest{

public BaseRequestApi(Context context, String url, OkInterface okInterface,
                      ErrorInterface errorInterface) {

    super(Method.GET, url, null, new BaseResponseApi(context,errorInterface, okInterface), new BaseErrorApi(context,errorInterface));

    configRequest(context);
}

private void configRequest(Object cancelTag) {
    this.setTag(cancelTag);
    this.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
  }
}


 @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        errorDelegate.onShowErrorResponse();
        if(error instanceof TimeoutError)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.time_out_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(error instanceof NetworkError)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.network_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(error instanceof NoConnectionError)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.no_connection_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(error instanceof ServerError)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.server_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if( response.length() > 0 ) {
        try {
            okDelegate.onOkResponse(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.unexpected_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            errorDelegate.doErrorHandler();
        }
    }else {
        errorDelegate.onShowErrorResponse();
        errorDelegate.doErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 significa Not Found, que la url esta mal y no pudo ser encontrada. Verifica que la url verdaderamente exista.

Comment: @Einer, cuando inserto un error en la url, la API me devuelve una estructura de error como en el ejemplo. Esta estructura la puedo ver devuelta desde postman, pero desde volley solo me retorna un error generico con statuscode 404. Necesito obtener esa estructura.

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez tu public_key definida dentro de Strings.xml es incorrecta o no existe.

Comment: Se que es incorrecta, quiero que me devuelva esa estructura de error para procesarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución la encontré acá:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038626/how-to-get-json-error-response-in-volley-onerrorresponse/42039254#42039254)

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2):

si estas obteniendo un error 404 al realizar la petición  mediante Volley o es la url a la cual realizaras la petición la cual no es correcta:

```
 getString(R.string.base_url),
```

o son los parametros enviados:

```
getString(R.string.payment_methods_url),
getString(R.string.public_key),
```

en este caso el error es que no se tiene una `public key` definida o es incorrecta:

```
"cause": [
    {
        "code": "1001",
        "description": "public_key not found"
    }
]
```

---

Esta es una descripción más especifica de los códigos de error:

> **400 BAD_REQUEST**

- 1000 Se requieren credenciales.
- 1001 `public_key` no encontrada.

> **401 UNAUTHORIZED**

- Sin autorización.

> **404 NOT_FOUND**

- No se encuentra recurso (`url`, `payment_methods_url` o `public_key` ).

Comment: Si, yo estoy probando la respuesta erronea, lo que me esta pasando es que no obtengo la esteuctura del error, osea : { "message": "invalid public_key", "error": "not_found", "status": 404, "cause": [ { "code": "1001", "description": "public_key not found" } ] }. Quiero de alguna forma que volley me retorne esta forma de error en el onErrorResponse ()